# How to add configuration type (SpringBootApplicationConfiguration) to Intellij so that it is recognized?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm using Community edition Intellij. In my application, in the application.xml I specify the type as SpringBootApplicationConfigurationType

```
<component name="Application">
  <configuration default="false" name="ExampleApplication" type="SpringBootApplicationConfigurationType" factoryName="Spring Boot">
    ....etc
  </configuration>
</component>
```

I get an error that says "Error running application: Unknown run configuration type SprintBootApplicationConfigurationType.

If I go to Windows -> Edit Configurations, it says "Run Configuration Error: Broken configuration due to unavailable plugin or invalid configuration data."

Comment: Do you use Ultimate or Community?

Comment: community, i'll add that to the question @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature [is available](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) only in the Ultimate edition:

[image: matrix]

Comment: ah... thank you :/ I'll accept it in when it lets me. Do you happen to know if this is "convertible" to eclipse?

Comment: I don't think it is.